# How to call A-BLoC function from B-BLoC function?

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-analytics, bloc

So, like most, I am new to Flutter, Bloc and Firebase Analytics. There are several ways to sync blocs by making one listen to another, but it quite doesn't match my situation as I'd like to keep track of some "Analytics related state variables".

```
AnalyticsBloc extends Bloc<AnalyticsEvent, AnalyticsState> {
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;

  @override
    FirebaseAnalyticsState get initialState => FirebaseAnalyticsState.initial();

  void setScreen(String currentScreen) {
    // sends and stores the currentScreen in Bloc State
    dispatch(SetScreenEvent(currentScreen));
  }

  void sendEvent(String eventName) {
    // uses the stored currentScreen in Bloc State
    dispatch(SendEventEvent(eventName));
  }
  ...
}
```

```
class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent, AppState> {
  @override
  AppState get initialState => AppState.initial();

  void someApplicationEvent() {
    // Problem: is there any way to trigger sendEvent from this Bloc?
    sendEvent('someAppEventTriggered');
    dispatch(ResetAppEvent());
  }
}
```

Problem: is there any way to trigger `AnalyticsBloc.sendEvent` from `AppBloc`?

Or should I just design it differently?

Comment: Regardless your case here you can call BlocA function from BlocB just import it and use it.

Comment: Assign the a-bloc instance in the constructor of b-block, so you create b-block like _bBloc = BBloc(aBloc: _aBloc);

Comment: Maybe you should split the idea into repository, and make bloc more clear on state management, so you could have an injection dependency instead of two state management. Not sure If this fits your scenario since I have no experience on `FirebaseAnalytics`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass blocA instance to blocB constructor and call function of blocA